# Changing Row/Column in Aggregate function in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, aggregation

Here is a SQL Function - sorry about the complexity;

```
SELECT [Codes].[Description], RawData.FS, COUNT(*)  As 'Total Units' 
FROM RawData, Codes, Categories  
WHERE RawData.ACR = Codes.Name
AND   Codes.CategoryName = 'ACR'
GROUP BY [Codes].[Description], [RawData].[FS]
ORDER BY [RawData].[FS]
```

In description - there is a Codes table that contains codes that are used in the table RawData for each of the columns. A second table called Categories keeps track of all these columns and Codes.CategoryName is a FK to Categories.Name. Basically creating a single lookup table for each of the coded values in RawData.

The field RawData.FS has 3 values NULL, 1, and 2. The RawData.ACR has 3 values corresponding to the descriptions of less than 1 acre, 1-10 acres, > 10 acres. The query above gives the correct results

```
Description                          FS Total Units
House on less than one acre               57080
House on one to less than ten acres        4760
House on ten acres or more                  880

House on less than one acre           1   31496
House on one to less than ten acres   1    4312
House on ten acres or more            1     360

House on less than one acre           2  594404
House on one to less than ten acres   2   74688
House on ten acres or more            2    9104
```

The challenge here is to redo the SQL so that instead of 3 sets of 3 rows, theirs is a column corresponding to values of FS. In other words the header would be (for the first row);

```
Description                        FS=NULL    FS=1      FS=2    
House on less than one acre         57080    31496    594404
```

As a little bit more help - here is the SQL to create the Category and Code structure

```
CREATE TABLE Categories (
 [Name] NVARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY,
 [Description] NVARCHAR(200) 
)

CREATE TABLE Codes (
 [Name] NVARCHAR(50),
 [CategoryName] NVARCHAR(50) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Categories(Name),
 [Description] NVARCHAR(200) )
```

Every field in RawData is coded (in fact the data dictionary is at http://www.census.gov/acs/www/Downloads/data_documentation/pums/DataDict/PUMS_Data_Dictionary_2009-2011.pdf ). This is one of those classic SQL puzzles.

Comment: The `Categories` table doesn't seem to be needed in your query: you have not specified a joining condition for the table, nor are you pulling any columns from it. And I wonder if adding it just like that, without a joining condition, doesn't skew the results you are trying to get from the query (multiplying them by 8, for instance).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to do the following which will *pivot* the `FS` values into columns:

```
SELECT [Codes].[Description], 
  sum(case when RawData.FS is null then 1 else 0 end) FS_null,
  sum(case when RawData.FS = 1 then 1 else 0 end) FS_1,
  sum(case when RawData.FS = 2 then 1 else 0 end) FS_2
FROM RawData
INNER JOIN Codes
  ON RawData.ACR = Codes.Name
INNER JOIN Categories  
  ON Codes.CategoryName = Categories.Name
WHERE Codes.CategoryName = 'ACR'
GROUP BY [Codes].[Description]
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested but it seems a case(s) and a subselect would work.

```
Select description, 
case when fs is null then total_units end as 'FS=Null',
CASE WHEN fs = 1 then total_units end as 'FS=1',
case when fs = 2 then total_units end as 'FS=2'
FROM (
  SELECT [Codes].[Description], 
  RawData.FS, COUNT(*)  As 'Total_units' 
  FROM RawData, Codes, Categories  
  WHERE RawData.ACR = Codes.Name
  AND   Codes.CategoryName = 'ACR'
  GROUP BY [Codes].[Description])
ORDER BY description
```